# mod_rewrite from querystring to path

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite the following URL:

http://www.example.com/services/user/get.json?(name)=(username)&token=abcdef

To:

http://www.example.com/services/user/(name)/(username).json?token=abcdef

The querystring variable's label `name` goes after `/user/`, then followed by the querystring variable `name`'s value `username`. Then `token` querystring variable should stay as it is.

So far I've come up with:

`RewriteRule ^/services/user/get\.json\?([name])=([^&]+)&(.+)$ /services/user/$1/$2?$3`

I'm quite bad at regex, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. If someone can help me out will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch your arguments with a RewriteCond, and after replace your url.

So you can try this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=([^&]+)&(.+)$
RewriteRule ^services/user/get.json /services/user/%1/%2.json?%3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: 1st, Thank you. 2nd, I'm having a problem with spaces in the value of querystring being double escaped. For example, `name=John Doe` becomes `name=John%20Doe` before it's rewritten, and after the rewrite it becomes `user/name/John%2520Doe`. Any light to shed on that?

Comment: There's a flag [NE] for "no escape", so nevermind :) Thank you again.